# Android: refresh/update fragment from another activity on button clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a Dialog prompt in `mainActivity`. If user close the Dialog, I need to show red dot to one of the ListView items inside `fourthFragment`(as per redbox in `fourthFragment` in image below).

The problem is the red dot only be updated after I close the app and reopened it, because `fourthFragment` already done created BEFORE user close the Dialog. How can I refresh/update the `fourthFragment` after Dialog closed so that red dot can be shown immediately?

short description:

- `mainActivity`: on Dialog closed > store `showRedDot`="1" to local db
- `fourthFragment`: onCreate > read `showRedDot` from local db, if "1", show red dot. ( problem here, when onCreate, `showRedDot` is still "0", so I need to update `fourthFragment` layout after dialog closed.)

[image]

Comment: Could you try refreshing the forth fragment from the main activity after dialog click?

Comment: One way is to use Local Broadcast Receiver, Broadcast the message on dialog close and listen the event in your fragment class. Not sure for performance.

Comment: Refresh your listview in some time of intervals using Handler() and notify it so you will overcome from this issue

Comment: @Niv hi can you show me how to refresh it?

Comment: @Kishan Soni hi thanks for your answer, I will research on it and try out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Interface or Broadcast receivers as above. If else refresh the fragment as

```
    // Reload current fragment
Fragment frg = null;
frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_Fragment_TAG");
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: thanks, I am able to update my red dot now. In fourthFragment onViewCreated(): `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(this, "general_setting_fragment_tag");` ; hence in mainActivity after dialog closed: `Fragment frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("general_setting_fragment_tag");
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();`

Answer (score 1):

You have calling a interface to push event dismiss(button click) of dialog.
Like this:

```
public interface MyDialogListener {
    void OnCloseDialog();
}

public class fourthFragment extend Fragment implements MyDialogListener {
    public void SomeMethod() {
        MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(this, this);
        myDialog.show();
    }

    public void OnCloseDialog() {
        // Do update your listview in here( maybe call method initialize data for listview)
    }

}

public class MyDialog extends Dialog {
    MyDialogListener mListener;

    public MyDialog (Context context, MyDialogListener listener) {
        super(context, R.style.Dialog);
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.CloseButton:
                // Push event when Dialog close(or anything)
                mListener.OnCloseDialog();
                dismiss()
                break;
            default:
                //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. Don't know if I did misundertand your code, my dialog is inside my `mainActivity`, but what I want to update is my `fourthFragment`, how can I implement your method to my case? Or let's say, how can I update my `fourthFragment` listview item from `mainActivity`?

Comment: You can listen event of dialog in mainActivity, make mainActivity have property like [public static MyDialogListener   dialogListener;]
 in fourthFragment  make [ mainActivity.dialogListener = new MyDialogListener (){
         public void OnCloseDialog() {
            //do update listview in here
        }
}
]